# Carpet Tile for maintaining Squeak subfloor

Tags: flooring, carpentry, carpet

I live in a larger two story 2000ft condo, where there are problems with carpet subfloor making squeaking sounds. After investigation, its due to loose subfloor screws or not being properly screwed into floor joist properly etc. Instead of moving all the furniture, and removing the carpet/padding which is a hassle. We are thinking of getting "Carpet Tile". Would carpet tile make things easier/quicker/remove to maintain in these situations, or is it best just to remove the Whole flooring to analyze the issue? In case it shows up again.

Sometimes the SqueakNoMore kits work for us, other times they don't in our experience.

Comment: If subfloor squeaks, it will keep on squeaking no matter what flooring you put on it.  Usually it comes down to fixing it right or living with it.  If you move the right way over the floor, record a disco record called Get down and squeak.  Please send me a part of the royalties.

Comment: hi @crip659 I am asking is carpet tile better to find the situation, and remove the carpet tile in that particular area, instead of moving All the furniture, and removing the whole regular carpet? talking about maintenance

Comment: @mattsmith5 - If you fix the problem correctly you won't have to worry about doing it over and over again.

Comment: What kind of carpet do you currently have? Do you have access to the underside of the floor? What is the subfloor made of and what are the joists made of?

Comment: its carpet, carpet padding, and plywood subfloor, I have fixed it before by screwing the subfloor to the joists properly cc @gnicko

Comment: Apparently not, @mattsmith5.

Comment: If fixed before and it comes back, there is a chance that loose screws not the only problem.  Might have to go beneath the sub floor to find the problem and fix it for good.

Comment: hi @crip659 what I am basically asking is, does carpet tile make it easier to remove floor and evaluate the issue, compared to regular carpet? I am not asking about the problem itself, but the diagnosis benefit. , also its different areas around the two story condo that may occur in the future, its old place, but I am looking for a easy "Diagnosis" solution

Comment: hi cc @gnicko comments above

Comment: If carpet tile is glued down like most tiles, then it is usually replacement than a take up job.  Carpets can be rolled up and reused, even if a pain in the neck.  Might be nicer with tiles, but would be hard for new tiles to match the old ones, even if you have extras from the first time.  Old ones will tend to have wear and fading to them that new replacements won't.  If just using double tape, might be able to reuse them.

Comment: hi @crip659 interesting, so you are saying there is no diagnostic benefit with carpet tiles, since once I peel back a Clean carpet tile, it will have to be replace anyways?interesting, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** You can pull up your existing carpeting and replace it with carpet tiles.

That *may* make it easier to diagnose issues with the floor/sub-floor without having to pull up existing carpet and remove the furniture from a room, but it will do nothing to actually fix the problem.

It's a *guarantee* that you'll have to pull up the existing carpet and more furniture in order to replace your current carpeting and you'll still be faced with the initial problem.

On the other hand, carpet tiles don't necessarily come up easily, especially in high-traffic areas where squeaking floors are most common.

Once you get a carpet tile up, putting it back down is another matter entirely. Sometimes they are damaged to the point that they need to be replaced. Sometimes not. Sometimes they just never look right afterward. The success of replacing the tile depends on the effects of aging exhibited by the original carpet and, to some extent, the availability of a replacement tile.

Another thing to consider is that squeaking floors can usually be fixed without having to remove any carpeting (or furniture). There are many [questions and answers here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=fix%20squeaking%20floor) (and the rest of the Internet) that deal with fixing a squeaky floor.

If you need advice on how to do that, please ask another question here as it seems to be outside the scope/intent of your original question.